# How to upload multiple images to firebase v9 storage and get all download URL 's to update it in cloud firestore database using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

[Vue dev tools screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rByAF.png)
[Console log Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzhIP.png)

### **Script Code:**

```
 import firebase from "@/firebase";
    import {
      getStorage,
      ref,
      uploadBytes,
      getDownloadURL,
      updateDoc,
    } from "firebase/storage";
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          imagesUrl: [],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        chooseFile() {
          document.getElementById("imgUpload").click();
        },
    
        uploadImage(e) {
          this.files.push(e.target.files[0]);
          this.images.push(URL.createObjetURL(this.files));
        },
        createCity: async function () {
          const docRef = firebase.addDoc(
            firebase.collection(firebase.firestoreDB, "cities"),
            {
              name: "Tokyo",
              country: "Japan",
            }
          );
    
          var photos = [];
    
          for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            // files.values contains all the files objects
            const file = this.files[i];
            const storage = getStorage();
            const metadata = {
              contentType: "image/jpeg",
            };
            const storageRef = ref(storage, "temp/" + docRef.id + "/" + file.name);
    
            const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);
            const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
            photos.push(downloadURL);
          }
          await console.log(photos);
          await updateDoc(docRef.id, { photosURLs: photos });
        },
      },
    };
```

### **Console Log Data:**

> - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   at VueComponent._callee$ (fragment.vue?262c:453:1)
>   at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63:1)
>   at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294:1)
>   at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119:1)
>   at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3:1)
>   at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25:1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use the `await` keyword within a `for` or a `forEach` loop, see [here](http://%20https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

You should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows (untested):

```
  const promises = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    // files.values contains all the files objects
    const file = this.files[i];
    const storage = getStorage();
    const metadata = {
      contentType: "image/jpeg",
    };
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "temp/" + docRef.id + "/" + file.name);

    promises.push(uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata).then(uploadResult => {return getDownloadURL(uploadResult.ref)}))
    
  }

  const photos = await Promise.all(promises);

  await console.log(photos);
  await updateDoc(docRef, { photosURLs: photos }); // <= See the change here docRef and not docRef.id
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for answering but that did not work. it's showing all photos in the console but not updating the photos in the firestore database

Comment: Yes, you need to call the last line of your code with `docRef` (the `DocumentReference`) and not `docRef.id`: `await updateDoc(docRef, { photosURLs: photos });`

Comment: Yeah I modified already from await updateDoc(docRef, { photosURls: photos}); but thats showing me a console log error: **TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**

Comment: I'm sorry there isn't enough info to debug your code. I'll suggest you use this extension: https://devtools.vuejs.org/

Comment: Yeah I also installed the VUE dev tools, I think its not showing any error over there. could you please check it for my sake I will give you a image link that contains screenshot please do check it, here it is: (Screen shot 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ar3_CRAD6SI9mnlRfDenvc2Jrf5UOysi/view?usp=sharing) (Screen shot 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqb3P5it5ixC7eLPoaqndkiMEekoScWC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please help me out. I'm so depended upon you..

Comment: Excuse me, R u there..